# Can we eliminate contrived questions?

Tags: discussion

I know this is day one, but let's be honest... some of these feel a lot like questions asked simply for the sake of asking them and populating the site. Should we enable some sort of filtering system to help eliminate the fluff and focus on the true problems?

For example... Eating ribs and avoiding BBQ sauce on the fingers. Really? Do we need a "lifehack" to avoid this problem?

IMO A perfect example of a true life hack would be this solution to this question: [How do I fill a hot water urn that doesn't fit in the sink?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/60/how-to-fill-a-hot-water-urn-when-it-doesnt-fit-in-the-sink)

Perhaps, we as a community should help regulate these with a "lifehack" tag and "tip" tag... Lifehack would be true lifehacks, and tips would be, well, tips. I wouldn't mind getting a tip for how to eat ribs cleanly... but it certainly isn't a "lifehack"

It's just my thought... Community? How can we police the created issues in the interest of a helpful site?

Comment: How are lifehacks different from tips? I think we need some kind of definition

Comment: A similar question could/should be asked about the tags in use. It's testing the limits of what's acceptable and what's not (which is pretty much the purpose of private beta).

Comment: The difficulty is that in most cases it's near impossible to tell if a question is contrived or an actual question

Comment: Even your "perfect example" can fail the common sense test. "Grab a smaller container, fill that, and dump it in the one that doesn't fit. Done". There only appears to be a clever solution once someone posts it. In the meantime, there's the obvious, common-sense, why-are-you-even-asking-about-this solution.

Comment: Related to this meta, or maybe they're even dupes: [Do questions asking for common-sense advice really count as asking about lifehacks?](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/43/168)

Answer (score 12):

> Lifehack would be true lifehacks, and tips would be, well, tips.

Sounds a bit *circular* doesn't it? You're going to need a better definition of what this site is about if you want to make it out of private beta — what's on topic and what's off topic — and it's going to have to be concise and easily understood by anyone who happens across this site. You can't have a site that's defined by the whims of whomever controls the close votes. If the leading reason to close a post is because it "isn't a lifehack", that creates a bad user experience for anyone who comes across it.

Answer (score 6):

As the poster of the ribs question, I thought I'd give my take on it.

This IS a question I posted to start populating the site. I thought it would be interesting to see a variety of questions and also see the types of answers we could get. I also thought this will help us to define what is and is not a lifehack. I guess the fact it stated this discussion should be a win. :-)

If this needs to be removed because it is to contrived in fine with that. If I should stop posting things during the beta to see what we want to accept and not accept them that is fine to.

Comment: We also did just get an answer about using corn holders which is probably the hackiest one so far! :-)

Comment: Personally, I too was interested in the ribs issue. It can be a real pain if you're having a console games and meat night, which I occasionally do.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the actual question being asked...

Comment: @ZachSaucier the answer to the question is we can remove this if we define that it is out of score. I don't feel we've done that yet so I posted some questions we can discuss to help create the definition.

Comment: ... I just like the idea of a "console games & meat night"

Answer (score 0):

> For example... Eating ribs and avoiding BBQ sauce on the fingers. Really? Do we need a "lifehack" to avoid this problem?

Definitely not. *Sometimes* on other sites we let a mediocre question live because the answers are really good, and so the page overall is a net win for the site. But the answers to that question are "use your fingertips" and "eat carefully". Nothing clever, nothing hard to think of, nothing interesting.

I'm not commenting on the rest yet as I want to see others from the community weigh in.

Comment: I think the question is good (and applicable to multiple people) and presents an interesting problem. I think the answers (thusfar) are low-quality and should be downvoted, but just because we can't think of a hacky solution, doesn't mean there *isn't* one.

Comment: @Nick, how does that help us define what's off topic, then? This makes *literally any how-to question* fair game for this site. Is that what we're going for?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I do know that penalizing a question because the answers aren't hacky isn't the way to go. Putting the burden on the asker to already have hacky solutions in mind is a sure-fire way to stop people asking (because they already have the solution).

Comment: @Nick That might make it more like a challenge site, which [has been floated](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/77/64). (I'm not sure what the right answer is.)

Comment: At this point, I think that these questions would be on-topic ***if*** the OP clarified what he already tried. See http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/1217/59 for more info.