# What if a question is unanswerable?

Tags: discussion, scope

From current answers on [What is a lifehack?](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/what-is-a-lifehack):

> A lifehack is a quick solution to a problem.
>
> [—](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19/137) [Bobo](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/75/bobo)

> I think that the very definition of what a lifehack is, is actually a solution, not a question.
>
> [—](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/59/137) [Adi Bradfield](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/111/adi-bradfield)

This reveals that **questions with no solutions are problematic**. Are they off-topic? What should we do about them?

Also relevant:

- [Can we eliminate contrived questions?](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10/137)

Comment: How do you know that a question has no solution, or if a question is "unanswerable"?

Comment: I did go on to say that even though the site is called life-hack, the scope doesn't have t be exclusively lifehacks. That would be near impossible to manage! Instead we should make a scope that is likely to lead to lifehack style answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This same issue occurs on other Stack sites. Sometimes well written, on topic, full questions do not have a known answer.

Provided the question is **in the scope** of Lifehacks and is clear, we should **leave questions that we don't think are answerable open**. Simply because we don't *think* it will be answerable doesn't mean that it *is*.

If the question is off topic for another reason, please close it for said reason. But "unanswerable" is not a valid close reason because we don't know everything.

Comment: What scope is that that you're referring to, though?

Comment: @abbyhairboat The one the community decides on through the other meta posts and questions accepted. This question only deals with an "unanswerable" close reason, which I argue shouldn't be a thing

Comment: OK, just checking.